# Caching of HTTP responses (HttpResponseCache)

Tags: android, http, caching, httpresponsecache

I'm trying to employ HttpResponseCache to cache each HTTP-request sent with HttpURLConnection.

But even if request goes to a resource 2'nd time the hit count always equals zero. Why it doesn't hit the cache?

Hit count:

```
import android.net.http.HttpResponseCache;
...
HttpResponseCache.getInstalled().getHitCount()
```

Usage:

```
for(byte i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   // Cache-Control:max-age=300
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://redbot.org/").openConnection(); 
    conn.setUseCaches(true);
    if(i == 1){
        try {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");
            InputStream cached = conn.getInputStream();
            // the resource was cached! show it
            Log.i(TAG, "cached");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // the resource was not cached
            Log.i(TAG, "NOT cached");
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I enable the cache:

```
File httpCacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "http");
long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
```

Comment: Have you find a solution to this?